# How do I request characters from a user, and then print the size of the characters?

Tags: c, char, scanf, sizeof

I'm very new to C, any help would be greatly appreciated.
I can't use the `<string.h>` or `<ctype.h>` libraries.
This is the code I have:

```
int main(void)
{
    char character;
    printf("Introduce characters: ");
    scanf(" %c", &character);
    printf("\nSize of character: %d", sizeof(character)/sizeof(char));
    
    return 0;
}
```

This only prints 1 as the size.

I read in another post that the problem was that initializing character by `char character;` would only let me store 1 single character. So, I modified it to be an array:

```
int main(void)
{
    char character[10];
    printf("Introduce maximum 10 characters: ");
    scanf(" %s", character);
    printf("\nSize of character: %d", sizeof(character)/sizeof(char));

    return 0;
}
```

The problem now is that by doing `character[10]`, it prints out that the size is 10. How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: `sizeof` tells you about a type, not about the value of any object.  Are you perhaps looking for the `strlen()` function?

Comment: You're using an incompatible format specifier for `sizeof`.  You need to use `%zu` or some other compatible format.  Your compiler should have warned about that.

Comment: The size of a container does not depend on the contents of that container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeof(character)/sizeof(char)` gives you the size of the array you declared, ***not*** the size of what the user has entered.

1. `sizeof(character)` gives the size of the entire array in bytes
2. `sizeof(char)` gives the size of a single character in bytes

So, when you do `sizeof(character)/sizeof(char)`, you get the actual size (i.e. number of elements) of your array. What you are trying to achieve can be done with `strlen()`. But since you can't use `<string.h>`, you can write it yourself:

```
int strlen2(char *s)
{
    int size;
    for (size = 0; s[size]; size++)
        ;
    return size;
}
```

Then use it like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char character[10];
    printf("Introduce maximum 10 characters: ");
    scanf("%s", character);
    printf("\nSize of character: %d", strlen2(character));
}
```

`strlen2()` counts the number of characters of your string, it stops counting when it encounters the first `\0` character (null terminator).

---

### Avoid using `scanf()` to read input

Your code is prone to bugs. If the user enters a string more than 9 characters long (don't forget the `\0` is added at the end of your string), you'll get a buffer overflow, because `character` is only supposed to contain 10 characters. You would want to limit the number of characters read into your string:

```
scanf("%9s", character); // Read only the first 9 characters and ignore the rest
```

Moreover, `scanf()` is used to *parse* input, not to actually read it. Use `fgets()` instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> // for strcspn()

int main(void)
{
    char character[10];
    printf("Introduce maximum 10 characters: ");
    
    if(!fgets(character, 10, stdin)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading input.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    character[strcspn(character, "\n")] = '\0'; // fgets() reads also `\n` so make sure to null-terminate the string
    
    printf("\nSize of character: %zu", strlen(character));
}
```

`fgets()` accepts three arguments:

- The first one is the array in which you want to store user input
- The second one is the size of your array
- The third one is the file stream you want to read from

It returns `NULL` on failure so you should check that as well.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I've edited the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well if you can't use any headers, maybe you can create a custom `strlen()` function.

`strlen()` pretty much counts all character until the `'\0'` character is found. `'\0'` is used to signify the end of string and is automatically appended by `scanf("%s",...)`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t ms_length(const char *s)
{
    size_t i = 0;

    for (; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
        ;

    return i;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *str = "hello";

    printf("%zu\n", ms_length(str));

    return 0;
}
```

And if you want to be pedantic, you might even want to check the return value of `scanf()`, for input errors and also apply a limit to the character to be read to avoid a buffer overflow.

```
if (scanf(" %9s", character) != 1) /* 9 characters + 1 reserved for \0 */
  { 
     /* handle error */
     return 1;
  }
```

Comment: Please note that in your customer `ms_length` function, the `len` variable is extraneous. You can simply return `i`.

Comment: That's great, but it's still returning `len`, and in this case the braces are unnecessary, as is the comparison, since `'\0'` is false in C. You can simply write `for (; s[i]; i++);`.

Comment: @Chris Thank you once again. Should be correct now.